# Mysql Data Directory on S3

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3

I want Mysql to store it's data on Amazone S3, So I mounted an S3 bucket to my server and changed the path of data dir to mounted directory in my.cnf.

After doing this, I restarted the server and created the database and it caused no problem but when I try to create a table (say test), it gives me the following error.

**ERROR 1033 (HY000): Incorrect information in file: './test/t.frm'**

Can any one please tell me, what I am trying to oo is actually possible?

If yes, where am I going wrong?

If no, Why?

Comment: what is the need of `S3 Bucket` to store `MySQL DB`?

Comment: I would be blown away if this works

Comment: @bluto I want to use cheaper storage such as S3 instead of something costlier like EBS or anything else.

Comment: The disk is not the most expensive part of this. The choice of EC2 type and going multi-az or not are much more significant. You could run RDS and then stop the instance when not using it as another option to save money.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no viable solution for storing MySQL databases on S3.  None.

There's nothing wrong with using s3fs in limited applications where it is appropriate, but it's not appropriate here.

S3 is not a filesystem.  It is an object store.  To modify a single byte of a multi-gigabyte "file" in S3 requires that the entire file be copied over itself.

Now... there are tools like s3nbd and s3backer that take a different approach to using S3 for storage.  These use S3 to emulate a *block device* over which you can create a filesystem, and these would come closer than s3fs to being an appropriate bridge between what S3 is and what MySQL would need, but still this approach cannot reliably be used either, for one reason.

Consistency.

When MySQL writes data to a file, it needs absolute assurance that if it reads that same data, that it will get back what it wrote.  S3 does not guarantee this.

> Q: What data consistency model does Amazon S3 employ?
>
> Amazon S3 buckets in all Regions provide read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects and eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

When an object in S3 is "modified" (that's done with an overwrite `PUT`), there is no guarantee that a read of that file won't return a previous version for a short time after the write occurred.

In short, you are pursuing an essentially impossible objective trying to use S3 for something it isn't designed to do.

There, is, however, a built-in mechanism in MySQL that can save on storage costs: [InnoDB natively supports on-the-fly table compression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-compression.html).

Or if you have large, read-only MyISAM tables, those can also be compressed with [`myisampack`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisampack.html).

Some EC2 instances include the [ephemeral disks/instance store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html), which are zero-cost, but volatile, hard drives that should never be used for critical data, but that might be a good option to consider if the database in question is a secondary database that can easily be rebuilt from authoritative sources in the event of data loss.  They can be quite nice for "disposable" databases, like QA databases or log analytics, where the database is not the authoritative store for the data.

Comment: Thanks for the InnoDB compression tip. That could be a game changer for my large-blob-infrequent-access use case.

Answer (score 3):

Actually s3 is not really a file system so it will not work as data directory in normal scenario.

May be you can use it as data directory after mounting it with data directory like /var/lib/mysql but still it will perform slow. So I don't think that it is a good idea.

S3 bucket is a storage directory where you can store your images, files, backup files etc.

If still you want to use it as data directory then you can take help from here.

http://centosfaq.org/centos/s3-as-mysql-directory/

Comment: I followed that link before posting here, but could not succeed.

Comment: Plz check if you are able to copy data from mounted s3 dir to your any other partition by cp command and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL with RocksDB engine can possibly do this:

1. Run [MyRocks](https://myrocks.io/) on S3FS, or
2. Use rockset's [RocksDB-Cloud](https://rockset.com/blog/rocksdb-cloud-enabling-the-next-generation-of-cloud-native-databases/) and modify MyRocks to support RocksDB-Cloud.

Both solutions might do some modification on MyRocks.

See source codes:

- [MyRocks](https://github.com/facebook/mysql-5.6)
- [RocksDB-cloud](https://github.com/rockset/rocksdb-cloud)

Answer (score 0):

files cannot be appended/modified in AWS S3 once created. It might be not be possible to store Mysql DB on S3.